# Jquery ui resizable doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create crop box for croping images, this is what i have done so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/7C8fp/1/

and everything is working perfectly except  `resizable` plugin, am i doing something wrong or is this jquery bug of some kind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the jQuery UI theme, if you add the following URL as a resource to your JSFiddle and hit run, it works:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Comment: Same here, I'm surprised it didn't.